# Adding Elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
array[3] = 4;
items_arr = 4;

System.out.println("The elements in the array are: ");
for (int x = 0; x < items_arr; x++)
    System.out.println("Array[" + x + "]=" + array[x]);
System.out.print("\n");

Scanner insert = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter an Element to Insert: ");
int input = insert.nextInt();

for (s = 0; s < items_arr; s++)
    if (array[s] == input)
        break;
items_arr++;
for (s = 0; s < items_arr; s++)
    System.out.println("Array[" + s + "]=" + array[s]);
break;
```

The output is. The elements are

```
Array [0]=  1
Array [1]=  2
Array [2]=  3
Array [3]=  4
```

Enter an element to Insert: 5

```
Array [0]=  1
Array [1]=  2
Array [2]=  3
Array [3]=  4
Array [4]=  0
```

when I insert 5 it posts 0
any suggestions please.. thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you've inserted the user inputted value into the array. How do you expect it to reflect in the output then?

Comment: copy current array in a new array and then insert `5` in new array

Comment: properly open-close `{}` your `if` and `for` and try againn

Comment: Prasad ... if i insert 5 it will show as array[4] = 5 not 0.. what is happening if i enter what i want to insert the result is 0

Comment: Satheesh im inside of a switch case...

Comment: so u want to insert only 1 element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert in to the array you shuould be doing follwoing operation

```
array[s]=input
```

Two notes here

1. Arrays are fixed length, and you should be checking the array length before inserting values in to that,other wise you will get `ArrayIndexOBException`. Safer to sue List/Set
2. As better coding practise, and to improve the readablity, you should be enclosing the conditional/loop statements  (such as `if` or `for`) - see eg below

eg: 1

```
for (int x = 0;x<items_arr;x++) {
    System.out.println("Array["+x+"]="+array[x]);
}
```

eg 2:

```
for(int s = 0; s < items_arr; s++) {
   if (array[s] == input) {
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not inserted `5` in your array,
do something  after `items_arr++`

```
array[ items_arr] = input;
```

If you do not insert any thing then by default every element is `0`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) type; I would recommend an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - that is -

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)  {
   al.add(i);
}

Scanner insert = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an Element to Insert: ");    
int input = insert.nextInt();
al.add(input);                         // And so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating/inserting the array with the new input.

```
for(s = 0; s < items_arr; s++)
    if (array[s] == input)
        break;
items_arr++;
```

just replace the above code with

```
array[ items_arr] = input;
items_arr++;
```